# Latest Build of ffmpeg Isn't Working

Tags: ffmpeg, git

[image]I've downloaded the latest git build of ffmpeg, extracted the folder, renamed it as usual and pasted to my C drive like the old version I had. If I delete the old folder and paste the new, cmd doesn't recognize ffmpeg commands. If I simply merge what is in the new folder with what was already on C, I end up still running the old build. The same is true if I delete and replace the duplicate doc and presets folders. I tried the release version as well as git and found the same issue.
What I've noticed is that the new folder doesn't have a bin or a licenses folder. This also means the new folder doesn't have any exe files in it. Is there a problem here or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I just downloaded the current git full 7z (2021-07-27) and verified that it contains all folders and files. You mention having the same issue with the release packages. Those haven't been updated since April 9 when the release was made.

Comment: I found the issue: my extraction tool ALzip just didn't feel like extracting everything in the 7z file. I forced it to and the contents of the bin folder were corrupt as Windows said it wasn't compatible with its version. So, I downloaded 7zip and behold it works fine. Conclusion: ALzip sucks.

Comment: @Huston Consider making that the answer to this question since you found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you downloaded the source code instead of `ffmpeg.exe`. FFmpeg only provides source code so you have to download it from third-party sites if you don't want to compile it.

See the [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page, go to the *Get packages & executable files* section, and choose your OS.

For Windows you can get `ffmpeg.exe` from:

- [gyan.dev](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/)
- [BtbN](https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/releases)

These are not some random sites as both providers are known in the FFmpeg community.

Comment: Thanks. I did download from gyan.dev and I thought I downloaded the correct file but maybe not. I added a screenshot to the original post for reference.